# No me esta funcionando la función de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Tengo esta función de JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function DisplayPug(val){ 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'inc/web/right/sub/match_stats.php?hash=' + val,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $("#match_box").html(html);
            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#match_box").offset().top},500,function(){
                ultimoscroll=$(window).scrollTop();
                animacion=false;
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

La uso de esta manera:

```
<tr onclick="DisplayPug(<?php echo $pug_history['pug_hash']?>)" class="<?php if (($pug_history['id'] % 2) == 0) { ?>tr_2<?php } else { ?>tr_1<?php } ?>">
```

Me voy a inspeccionar elemento y veo que me esta funcionando, pero al dar clic no abre el PHP que estoy asignando en la función de JavaScript, no me genera ningún log para saber que error puede estar dándome.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el PHP donde me tiene que redirigir tengo la función así:

```
$ext_query = "";
if(isset($_GET['hash']))
{
    $ext_query = " where pug_hash='".$_GET['hash']."'";
}

$ext_query2 = "";
if(isset($_GET['hash']))
{
    $ext_query2 = " where pug_hash='".$_GET['hash']."'";
}

$dbTable = "server_match";

$query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$dbTable .$ext_query) or die ("Error en la consulta: ".mysqli_error($db));

$query2 = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `users_match` '.$ext_query2.' ORDER BY user_frags DESC') or die ("Error en la consulta: ".mysqli_error($db));

$query3 = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `users_match` '.$ext_query2.' ORDER BY user_frags DESC') or die ("Error en la consulta: ".mysqli_error($db));
```

Comment: ayuda pls, intente cambiando el valor de pug_hash en esta parte
<tr onclick="DisplayPug(<?php echo $pug_history['pug_hash']?>)" class="<?php if (($pug_history['id'] % 2) == 0) { ?>tr_2<?php } else { ?>tr_1<?php } ?>">

a una id que solo me genera numeros que si 1, 2, 3, 4 etc y si me funciona pero colocando con el valor de pug_hash que me genera numeros y letra asi como se ve en la foto no me funciona

Comment: Creo que tu error está en las comillas, tu tienes `onclick="DisplayPug(1a75fbf6)"` el argumento debería estar como string es decir con comillas `DisplayPug('1a75fbf6')`,  (debes fijarte bien en la diferencia, porque las comillas ( ' ) a penas se notan) entonces tu código debería ser algo así: `onclick="DisplayPug('<?php echo $pug_history['pug_hash']?>')"`

Comment: Además de lo dicho, tu llamada ajax carece de manejo de errores, al menos mientras desarrollas podrías agregar algo como: `error: function(xhr){alert("Error: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);`

Comment: jachguate, eso de que me servirá disculpa la pregunta estoy aprendiendo?

Comment: Yussef. muchas gracias me funciono :D